# When adding package to PyPi SSL error occurs

Tags: python, ssl, pypi, twine

I am trying to add a package to PyPi so I can install it with Pip. I am trying to add it using `twine upload dist/*`.

This causes me to get multiple SSL errors such as `raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='upload.pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /legacy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))`.

I am using a school laptop and I presume that this is something my administrator has done however I can install stuff with pip by using `pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-h\ost files.pythonhosted.org`.
 I was wondering if there was another to add my package to pip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is your school has something in place where they are replacing the original cert with their own, you could maybe get around it using `--cert` and referencing the path for your schools cert, but I think an easier workaround is to copy the files to a non school computer and upload from there.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things, including an out-of-date version of `twine`, or (more likely) an out-of-date version of OpenSSL. Some possible solutions are listed here: https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/273